# postgreSQL function select from list

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-9.6

I'm new to PostgreSQL and any other databases.
I was trying to create a function (we are on version 9.6) that can select a temporary hashed password from a list and update the table and return the non hashed value, for example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION updatePassword(_id varchar ) RETURNS varchar AS
$do$
BEGIN
        -- randomly select one
        -- passowrd1, hashedPasswordValue1
        -- password2, hashedPasswordValue2
        -- passowrd3, hashedPasswordValue3
        -- password4, hashedPasswordValue4

        UPDATE accounts 
        SET "password" = **hashedPasswordValue4**, last_password_change = NOW()
        WHERE id = _id ;
         
    
   RETURN 'The password has been updated successfully to **password4**';

END;
$do$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Or if it's no possible what alternatives are there to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can declare an array in your function and then hash a random value from the array when you update the record

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION updatePassword(_id int) RETURNS varchar AS
$do$
DECLARE
  list_password text[] := '{pass_1, pass_2, pass_3}'; 
  selected_password text = list_password[1 + floor((random() * array_length(list_password, 1)))::int];
BEGIN   
   UPDATE accounts 
      SET "password" = md5(selected_password), last_password_change = NOW()
   WHERE id = _id ; 
   RETURN CONCAT('The password has been updated successfully to ', selected_password);
END;
$do$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

select updatePassword(1)
```

Or you can generate a random value so as not to fill the array

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION updatePassword(_id int) RETURNS varchar AS
$do$
DECLARE 
  random_password text = trunc(random() * 99999999);
BEGIN   
   UPDATE accounts 
      SET "password" = md5(random_password), last_password_change = NOW()
   WHERE id = _id ; 
   RETURN CONCAT('The password has been updated successfully to ', random_password);
END;
$do$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

select updatePassword(1)
```

Demo in [DBfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=ca7ea8aa2a6766278b697ca0abe40369)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a pair of CTE's to generate and then hash the password.
This isn't to recommend numeric passwords or met hashes, rather to demonstrate the CTE method.

> ```
> create table accounts(id int, last_password_change date, password varchar(1000));
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> insert into accounts (id) values
> (1)
> ```

1 rows affected

> 

> ```
> with r as (
>   select 
>   substring(random()::varchar,3,4)
>     as pword 
> ),
> u as (
>    UPDATE accounts 
>    SET "password" = 
>      (select md5(pword)
>       from r), 
>     last_password_change = NOW()
>    WHERE id = 001
>    returning id
> )
> SELECT 'id' " ", id::varchar from u
> union all
> select 'password', pword::varchar from r
> ```
>
> ```
>          | id  
> :------- | :---
> id       | 1   
> password | 1587
> ```

> ```
> select * from accounts;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | last_password_change | password                        
> -: | :------------------- | :-------------------------------
>  1 | 2022-04-29           | 49af6c4e558a7569d80eee2e035e2bd7
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=fe1c8893c43b5f29d9bfd0c2def4b15a)*

Comment: `gen_random_uuid` function is not available in version 9.6